# replace id attribute in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I asked another question on this , and got an answer , but still managed to mess it up.  I have a for loop , and I want to make clones of a template in my for loop.  I would like each id to be replaced with the id + 0 the first time through the loop.  So textbox with id `tFirstName` would be `tFirstName0` and id `tLastName` would be `tLastName0` and so on...   Then for the next clone , then next time through the loop it would be tFirstName1 , tLastName1, ect..

The problem with this code is that `i` is adding one for every text box, so in the first template the id's are `tFirstName0`, `tLastName1`, ect..

I am looking for - if someone has a suggestion to keep `i` uniform through out the for loop, then increase , then stay uniform through the next loop

```
 var NumofClones = (4 * 1);
            for (i = 0; i < NumofClones; i++) {
                var newrow = $('._template').clone().removeClass('_template');
                newrow.find('input[type=text]').attr('id', function (i, oldID) {
                    return oldID + i
                });

                $('.placenewrows').append(newrow);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `i` in the `.attr()`'s callback function refer to the parameter `i`, not the `i` in the for loop, change the parameter `i` of the callback function to some others.

```
 var NumofClones = (4 * 1);
 for (var i = 0; i < NumofClones; i++) {
     var newrow = $('._template').clone().removeClass('_template');
     newrow.find('input[type=text]').attr('id', function (index, oldID) {
         return oldID + i;
     });
     $('.placenewrows').append(newrow);
 }
```

Comment: working late on Sunday nights leads to stupid mistakes like defining i twice and not noticing , i was only there for an old function that is no longer needed , thanks